# python pandas dataframe, sum running total of values and if an amount is reached change value of cell, insert duplicate row and add balance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each 'name' I would like to count the 'hours' column in descending order, then if the hours reach 38 for a 'name' I need to:

Insert a new row (in green) underneath the row that reached the 38th hour (call this old row; in blue).

add the hours remaining to reach 38 in the old row (4.5 for Ankit and 8 for Abhishek)

add the balance of the original value to the new value in the row/cell below

Below is the code that reflects the BEFORE. No need to include colours I just added them for presentation

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['number'] = (651,651,651,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,8806,8806,8806,6841,6841,6841,6841)

df['name']=('Alex','Alex','Alex','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Abhishek','Abhishek','Abhishek','Blake','Blake','Blake','Blake')

df['hours']=(8.25,7.5,7.5,7.5,14,12,15,11,6.5,14,15,15,13.5,8,8,8,8)

df['loc']=('Nar','SCC','RSL','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNI','UNI','UNI','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING')

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` operations:

```
# compute cumsum
s = df.groupby('number')['hours'].cumsum()
# identify value above threshold
m = s.gt(38)
idx = m.groupby(df['number']).idxmax()

# compute difference from previous sum to 38
delta = s.groupby(df['number']).shift().rsub(38).fillna(s)

# duplicate rows
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df.index.isin(idx)&m)+1)]

# update
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(keep='last'), 'hours'] = delta
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(), 'hours'] -= delta

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    number      name  hours     loc
0      651      Alex   8.25     Nar
1      651      Alex   7.50     SCC
2      651      Alex   7.50     RSL
3     4267     Ankit   7.50  UNIT-C
4     4267     Ankit  14.00  UNIT-C
5     4267     Ankit  12.00  UNIT-C
6     4267     Ankit   4.50  UNIT-C
6     4267     Ankit  10.50  UNIT-C
7     4267     Ankit  11.00  UNIT-C
8     4267     Ankit   6.50  UNIT-C
9     4267     Ankit  14.00  UNIT-C
10    8806  Abhishek  15.00     UNI
11    8806  Abhishek  15.00     UNI
12    8806  Abhishek   8.00     UNI
12    8806  Abhishek   5.50     UNI
13    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
14    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
15    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
16    6841     Blake   8.00  UNKING
```

Comment: close! however:

1. Ankit should have had a row inserted under row 6 with the balance of 10.5 (15-4.5) added as the hours and remaining cells copied from row 6

2. same as above for Abhishek; a row to add the balance of 5.5 (13.5-8) should have been inserted
    
The above points are reflected in my screen shot

Comment: @ds882 indeed, see update

Comment: Solved. Thank you. Would you also know how to make the row that is adjusted and the row that is inserted (i.e. the blue and green row) a colour.

Comment: I have created a further request regarding colour in following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480213/python-pandas-dataframe-add-colour-to-adjusted-and-inserted-row