# python pandas dataframe add colour to adjusted and inserted row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors

I have the following data-frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['number'] = (651,651,651,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,4267,8806,8806,8806,6841,6841,6841,6841)
df['name']=('Alex','Alex','Alex','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Ankit','Abhishek','Abhishek','Abhishek','Blake','Blake','Blake','Blake')
df['hours']=(8.25,7.5,7.5,7.5,14,12,15,11,6.5,14,15,15,13.5,8,8,8,8)
df['loc']=('Nar','SCC','RSL','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNIT-C','UNI','UNI','UNI','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING','UNKING')
print(df)
```

If the running balance of an individuals hours reach 38 an adjustment to the cell that reached the 38th hour is made, a duplicate row is inserted and the balance of hours is added to the following row.  The following code performs this and the difference in output of original data to adjusted data can be seen.

```
s = df.groupby('number')['hours'].cumsum()
m = s.gt(38)
idx = m.groupby(df['number']).idxmax()
delta = s.groupby(df['number']).shift().rsub(38).fillna(s)
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat((df.index.isin(idx)&m)+1)]
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(keep='last'), 'hours'] = delta
out.loc[out.index.duplicated(), 'hours'] -= delta
print(out)
```

I then output to csv with the following.

```
out.to_csv('Output.csv', index = False)
```

I need to have the row that got adjusted and the row that got inserted highlighted in a color (any color) when it is exported to csv.

UPDATE: as csv does not accept colours to output, any way to tag the adjusted and insert rows is acceptable

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The CSV format doesn't support colours, you'd better look into exporting your dataframe to a spreadsheet (Excel or Google Sheets) to achieve this. For example see: https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/how-to-color-cells-dynamically-in-excel-based-of-formula-done-from-python/

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I didn't know colours couldn't output colours.  I provided an update UPDATE: as csv does not accept colours to output, any way to tag the adjusted and insert rows is acceptable

Comment: possibly having another column that tags adjusted and inserted rows

Comment: UPDATE: an adjusted version of this question has been posted in the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496801/python-pandas-dataframe-add-column-and-tag-an-adjusted-and-inserted-row

Answer (score 1):

You can't add any kind of formatting, including colors, to a CSV. You can however color records in a dataframe.

```
# single-index:
# Load a dataset
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('planets')# Now let's group the data
groups = df.groupby('method').mean()
groups

# Highlight the Maximum values
groups.style.highlight_max(color = 'lightgreen')
```

[image]

```
# multi-index:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['one', 'A', 100,3], ['two', 'A', 101, 4], 
                   ['three', 'A', 102, 6], ['one', 'B', 103, 6], 
                   ['two', 'B', 104, 0], ['three', 'B', 105, 3]],
   columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']).set_index(['c1', 'c2']).sort_index()
print(df)


def highlight_min(data):
    color= 'red'
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

    if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
        is_min = data == data.min()
        return [attr if v else '' for v in is_min]
    else: 
        is_min = data.groupby(level=0).transform('min') == data
        return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_min, attr, ''),
                            index=data.index, columns=data.columns)


df = df.apply(highlight_min, axis=0)
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue is the real life data is large and I need the data to be output to excel or csv. I didn't know colours couldn't output colours. I provided an update as follows - UPDATE: as csv does not accept colours to output, any way to tag the adjusted and insert rows is acceptable

Comment: UPDATE: an adjusted version of this question has been posted in the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496801/python-pandas-dataframe-add-column-and-tag-an-adjusted-and-inserted-row